# select from one column if

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have table like this

```
yr      subject     winner

2008    Economics   Paul Krugman
2008    Medicine    Harald zur Hausen
2007    Peace       Al Gore
2007    Physics     Albert Fert
2006    Chemistry   Roger D. Kornberg
2006    Physics     George F. Smoot
2005    Chemistry   Yves Chauvin
2005    Economics   Thomas C. Schelling
```

and I need to select year if only 'subject != 'Chemistry'
I mean I want the query output to be like

```
yr
2008
2007
```

Thanks.

Comment: which is your database ?? you have tagged `mysql` and `oracle` both

Comment: I hope answer works :)

Comment: Then why do you have Oracle tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your query as below for Mysql

```
select yr
from t 
group by yr
having sum(subject ='Chemistry') = 0
```

Above query will return only years which doesn't contains subject ='Chemistry'

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/984eb/1)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid yes, That what I'm locking for, Appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct yr from table_name where subject not like 'chemistry'
```

Comment: Anepu that will produce all years

Comment: select distinct yr from table_name where yr not in(select yr from table_name where subject like 'chemistry' )

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT yr FROM table_name WHERE yr not in (select yr FROM table_name WHERE subject ='Chemistry')`

Comment: Why such complicated?